# ¿Es "manzana de Adán" el término de uso común en América para la nuez de la garganta?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, sustantivos, hispanoamérica

En España usamos la palabra *[nuez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QhuRjo1)* como:

> Prominencia que forma el cartílago tiroides en la parte anterior del cuello del varón adulto.

En inglés se usa el término *Adam's apple*, que vi literalmente traducido en los subtítulos de un documental de Netflix como *[manzana de Adán](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OItjStD#9hqx3mt)*. Buscando en el diccionario resulta que el término no solo existe en español, sino que además parece que se usa en toda América. Quise concretar un poco más, pero el término no aparece en el de americanismos, tan solo aparece recogido que *[manzana](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=manzana)* (sin más) se puede usar como abreviatura vulgar de *manzana de Adán* en algunos países.

Así pues, mi pregunta es si *manzana de Adán* es realmente el término que se usa comúnmente en toda América para designar a la nuez de la garganta, o si se restringe a ciertos países. ¿Se usa en tono formal o informal? ¿Se entiende allí el término *nuez*?

---

- *Manzana* aparece ya como "nuez de la garganta" en el Alemany y Bolufer de 1917, marcado como de uso en Chile. En 1925 aparece en el DLE. Estos son los primeros registros, sería interesante saber desde cuándo se usa.
- *Nuez del cuello* aparece ya en el diccionario de Nebrija de 1495, traducido al latín como *epiglottis*.

Answer (score 5):

Según el [*Diccionario de americanismos*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?key=manzana) (mira a la entrada final al pie de la página), sí - se usa en *muchos* países de hispanoamérica:

> **a.** ǁ    ~ **de Adán.** <sub>(Calco del ingl. Adam's apple).</sub> loc. sust. *EU, Mx, Ho, ES, Ni, CR, Pa, RD, PR, Co, Ve, Ec, Pe, Bo, Ch, Py, Ar.* En los hombres, nuez de la garganta. **◆ manzana.**

Comment: Lo que es no darme cuenta de que la página tenía una barra de _scroll_ y que me quedaba aún artículo por leer... no debí haberme despertado tan temprano hoy...

Comment: termino católico mas que nada... me parece extraño que en américa sea mas común que en españa

Comment: En Colombia siempre la hemos llamado Manzana de Adán. Me contaban cuando era pequeño que se debía a que era un simbolismo de que _"la manzana que Eva le dió se le quedó atorada"_ en la garganta. :-) El término "nuez" nos es desconocido.

Comment: En Chile se usa más la palabra nuez de Adán.

Answer (score 1):

En Argentina decimos **nuez de Adán**.

(Le acabo de preguntar a 5 argentinos).

En [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuez_de_Ad%C3%A1n) se explica de donde proviene la confusión entre nuez y manzana de Adán:

> Hay dos versiones principales que tratan de explicar el por qué se le conoce como «manzana» o «nuez de Adán». Una de ellas es registrada en el Brewer's Dictionary of Phrase and Fable y en la edición de 1913 del Webster's Dictionary. Esta versión apunta a una antigua creencia de que una pieza del fruto prohibido se incrustó en la garganta de Adán (el primer hombre, según las religiones abrahámicas).​ No obstante, no está claro el origen ni el lugar de dicha historia ya que ésta no se encuentra en la Biblia ni tampoco en otros escritos judeocristianos, además de que no se describe cuál era el tipo de fruta que comió Adán.
>   [...]

**Que conste que no he leído la biblia, por lo que no sé mucho al respecto.** Parece que no se sabe con certeza si Adán comió una manzana, pero como la historia dice que se incrusto una pieza del fruto, carozo o semilla, puede que accidentalmente se lo confundió con una nuez.

Comment: Adán se comió fue una manzana. Es curioso que mezclen nuez con Adán.

Comment: @DGaleano pues es así, yo soy argentino.

Comment: ¿Por que los votos en borrar? / Why the delete votes?

Comment: No pongo en duda que seas Argentino o que así lo usen. Lo que digo es que me parece curioso que se mezclen cosas sin relación pero así es el idioma y tu aporte hace que nos enteremos que eso pasa. Y respecto al otro comentario, cuando alguien deja respuestas de una sola línea muchos en este sitio tienden a verlas no como respuestas sino como comentarios tal como se describe en la sección https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer Nota que tu respuesta no responde a **"manzana de Adán es el término que se usa en América para designar la nuez de la garganta?"**

Comment: Porque borran los comentarios y respuestas de la gente?

Comment: @DGaleano, acabo de notar que habías editado tu comentario. En mi respuesta, estoy diciendo que en la Argentina (la cual es parte de América), no se utiliza el termino, por lo tanto la respuesta es **no**. No en todos los países de América se utiliza manzana de Adán.